# Historical: I am trying to get a handle on when output voltage was used to protect from faulty LEDs

Tags: led, over-voltage-protection

I am interested in when a simple over voltage detector was first used to protect LED arrays from damage caused by one faulty unit. I have a reference from 1999 but am sure I saw something first implemented in the mid 90's - memory not helping!

Comment: Over voltage protection is not some patent specific to LEDs. So I am pretty sure that it was used with the very first LED driver circuits.

Comment: There are chips for open circuit protection in strings

Answer (score 0):

I found several patents from mid-late 1998:
https://patents.google.com/patent/GB2341018A
https://patents.google.com/patent/DE19841490A1/en

This patent from 1995 includes overvoltage protection for the LED circuit, but it isn't specifically there to protect the LEDs from each other:
https://patents.google.com/patent/EP0686953A1/en

This patent from 1989 also isn't intended for an array of LEDs, but it does feature a lamp that is switched off in the case of overvoltage which could be adapted to fit what you described:
https://patents.google.com/patent/US5068570A/en